# Photo saved from Illustrator Showing Blurry in Photoshop Elements

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I changed the color of a vector in Illustrator to use in PSE (I don't have enough experience in Illustrator to move all my work over there). The image is so crisp in Illustrator but when I open in PSE it's blurry. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I no longer use Illustrator, but have used many Adobe products. The first thing I would advise is to start using the Help menu for questions on how to make the most out of sharing our image between them. Next. The file type of the Illustrator image you intend to open in PS is important. Under the FILE menu tab, there should be a *Paths To Photoshop* selection to help you make the right choice. In the past, depending on the complexity of the image I was working on, I could directly copy from Ill. and paste in PS. and vise versa.